# Python String issue while using the %

Tags: python, string

While I am trying to store this line as a string in my code I am getting the error:

> ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 78

The line/code which i am storing in Python is

> "select {emp.uid} as empid from { Employee as emp} where {emp.uid} like '%%s%'"%somedata
> Could Someone suggest me what I am doing wrong, also those ' are necessary

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, try to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of what this does as I don't know SQL but both of these strings are accepted on Python:

```
"select {emp.uid} as empid from { Employee as emp} where {emp.uid} like '%%%s%%' " % somedata

"select {emp.uid} as empid from { Employee as emp} where {emp.uid} like '%s' " % somedata
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks the first string works for me and this is not sql it is flexisearch related to SAP product